# ModuleNotFoundError when trainng on a custom Azure environment

Tags: python, azure, tensorflow, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-container-registry

I have a tensorflow script that works perfectly when trained on ACR image: AzureML-tensorflow-2.7-ubuntu20.04-py38-cuda11-gpu (mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/curated/tensorflow-2.7-ubuntu20.04-py38-cuda11-gpu:28)

I need to include a few additional dependencies so I'm creating a custom environment (conda.yml and code included below). The environment image is build successfully, but when I execute the training job, it complains that tensorflow is not found.

In my conda.yml, I've commented out the packages that are already included in tensorflow-2.7-ubuntu20.04-py38-cuda11-gpu. If I do not comment them, then the image creation fails.

conda.yml:

```
name: keras-env
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.8
  - pip=20.2.4
  - pip:
    #- protobuf~=3.20
    #- numpy~=1.21.0
    #- tensorflow-gpu~=2.7.0
    #- matplotlib~=3.5.0
    #- azureml-mlflow==1.51.0
    #- horovod[tensorflow-gpu]~=0.23.0
    - azureml.core
    - keras
    - mlflow
    - pyarrow
    - idx2numpy
    - scikit-learn
```

Code for environment build:

```
import os
from azure.ai.ml.entities import Environment

custom_env_name = "stb-dist-keras-env"
dependencies_dir = "./"

from azure.ai.ml import MLClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

ml_client = MLClient(
    DefaultAzureCredential(), 'a', 'ab', 'abc'
)

job_env = Environment(
    name=custom_env_name,
    description="Custom environment distributed environment",
    conda_file=os.path.join(dependencies_dir, "conda.yml"),
    image="mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/curated/tensorflow-2.7-ubuntu20.04-py38-cuda11-gpu:28"
)
job_env = ml_client.environments.create_or_update(job_env)

print(
    f"Environment with name {job_env.name} is registered to workspace, the environment version is {job_env.version}"
)
```

This is the error reported in the std_log

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "train.py", line 18, in
>
> import tensorflow as tf ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

Update 1: Including additional data.

This is my [train.py](https://github.com/horovod/horovod/blob/master/examples/tensorflow2_keras_mnist.py). I'm using the same train.py between the two runs.

Custom environment succeeded: [image: Custom environment]

Succeeded on MCR environment: [image: succeeded on mcr image]

Failed on custom environment: [image]

Code to kick off the job:

```
from azure.ai.ml import command, MpiDistribution

job = command(
    code="./",  # local path where the code is stored
    command="python train.py --epochs ${{inputs.epochs}}",
    inputs={"epochs": 1},
    #environment="AzureML-tensorflow-2.7-ubuntu20.04-py38-cuda11-gpu@latest",
    environment="stb-dist-keras-env@latest",
    compute="",
    instance_count=1,
    distribution=MpiDistribution(process_count_per_instance=1),
    display_name="tensorflow-mnist-distributed-horovod-example"
    # experiment_name: tensorflow-mnist-distributed-horovod-example
    # description: Train a basic neural network with TensorFlow on the MNIST dataset, distributed via Horovod.
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be wanting to use `tensorflow` instead of `tensorflow-gpu`.

According to `tensorflow-gpu` [in PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-gpu/):

> tensorflow-gpu has been removed. Please install tensorflow instead. The tensorflow package supports GPU accelerated operations via Nvidia CUDA.

There's also a removal information in PyPI

> Removal Information
> tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu have been the same package since TensorFlow 2.1, released in September 2019. Although the checksums differ due to metadata, they were built in the same way and both provide GPU support via Nvidia CUDA. As of December 2022, tensorflow-gpu has been removed and has been replaced with this new, empty package that generates an error upon installation.

> All existing versions of tensorflow-gpu are still available, but the TensorFlow team has stopped releasing any new tensorflow-gpu packages, and will not release any patches for existing tensorflow-gpu versions.

There's also a warning:

> This simple package raises a warning if setup.py is executed as part of a package installation. This intentionally prevents users from installing the package.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, but my training script isnt changing between the 2 runs. It's not using tensorflow-gpu. Here is the link to the script:

https://github.com/horovod/horovod/blob/master/examples/tensorflow2_keras_mnist.py